# Calling AWS Textract from another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I am currently using AWS Textract for some OCR service, which is available in some regions. 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-textract-now-generally-available/

My EC2 servers however, are in Singapore. 
Just would like to ask, if it is possible to call AWS Textract from an EC2 server that is Singapore region based? (Asia Pacific) Singapore. 
Will I experience any issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can just change the default region before making Textract API calls. It should work without any issues but be aware that you will experience increased latency and you'll be charged for inter-region data transfer.

Data Transfer Out From Amazon EC2 to another region: ~$0.09 per GB

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
aws textract detect-document-text ...
```

Comment: One thing is realised is that the s3 bucket from which textract gets the PDF from has to be in the same region.